# Angular Dialog: No component factory found for DialogModule.

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog, components

Trying to make a dialog using feature model in angular 6. But I'm getting this error:

> No component factory found for DialogModule. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Everyone keeps saying to use

> entryComponents: [DialogComponent]

which I am already doing. Also tried to use that in the feature module without success. Here are I think the necessary and simplified files:

app.module.ts

```
import { DialogModule } from './components/dialog/dialog.module';
import { DialogComponent } from './components/dialog/dialog.component';
...

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [..., AppComponent],
  imports: [DialogModule],
  entryComponents: [DialogComponent],

  providers: [..., MatDialogModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

dialog.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DialogComponent } from './dialog.component';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [..., DialogComponent],
  exports: [DialogComponent]
})
export class DialogModule {
  ...
}
```

some-other.component.ts

```
import { DialogModule } from '../../components/dialog/dialog.module';
...

@Component({
    ...
})

export class LanguageButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private languageService : LanguageService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,) {
  }

  // activated from button
  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(DialogModule);
  }
}
```

How to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I couldn't read the error message properly. Fix was to change:

```
this.dialog.open(DialogModule);
```

to

```
this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
```

Another reminder that if you can't find a solution to simple problem from searching web, it's most likely a typo.

Answer (score 25):

You have to put your `DialogComponent` in `entryComponents` of `DialogModule` and not in `AppModule`:

1. Place the `entryComponents` in the correct module

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

    import { DialogComponent } from './dialog.component';
    ...

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ],
      declarations: [DialogComponent],
      exports: [DialogComponent],
      entryComponents: [DialogComponent],
    })
    export class DialogModule {
        ...
    }
```

2. Remove `entryComponents` from `AppModule`

Comment: Yeah my op was a result of trying different things to make it work. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Did it worked? If yes, please, mark the answer as the correct one. If not, give me feedback and I can try to fund another way...

Comment: Both ways worked after I corrected my typo that I answered earlier but couldn't mark for answer for 2 days because of limitations.

Answer (score 10):

I was using [this](https://wrappixel.com/demos/admin-templates/material-pro/landingpage/index.html) theme and the modal dialog was opening on the left side of screen and was completely invisible like this

[image]

and throwing error

> ERROR Error: No component factory found for DialogOverviewExampleDialogComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

[image]

but was working fine in dialog component which rest inside material root.

[image]

and If you checked the material modules you will see we need

> DemoMaterialModule

and entry point

> entryComponents: [DialogOverviewExampleDialogComponent]

because dialog component need this

[image]

So simply the solution is to use this module and entry point inside your component module in my case my component module is **page.module.ts**
so I just need to add them and it works

```
//This is important
entryComponents: [DialogOverviewExampleDialogComponent]
,
declarations: [
MatIconComponent,
TimelineComponent,
InvoiceComponent,
PricingComponent,
HelperComponent,
SiteSearchComponent,

UserAdminComponent,
CreateUserComponent,
ManageUserComponent ,
//This is important   
DialogOverviewExampleDialogComponent
```

**Result**

[image]

Also instead of using predefined dialogue you could create your own by just renaming the component inside your component like

```
 @Component({
selector: 'app-create-dialog-overview-example-dialog',
template: `<h1 mat-dialog-title class='data.class'>{{data.title}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content >
<p>{{data.message}}</p>

</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
<button mat-button tabindex="2" (click)="onNoClick()">Ok</button>

</div>`
})
export class YOURDIALOGCOMPONENTNAMEHERE {
constructor(
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<YOURDIALOGCOMPONENTNAMEHERE>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
) {


 }

onNoClick(): void {
this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

and when open dialog

```
openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(YOURDIALOGCOMPONENTNAMEHERE,{
      width: '250px',
      data: { message: this.statusMessage ,class:this.class,title:this.title}

    });
```

Finally add this in your root module component and entry

```
entryComponents:[YOURDIALOGCOMPONENTNAMEHERE],
declarations:[YOURDIALOGCOMPONENTNAMEHERE
```

Answer (score 2):

*If the module in which you are using the component is a lazy loaded module, then you need to import the **MatDialogModule** within the same module*, else you will get the same error even if you add your component to entryComponents or maybe you can created a shared module for material components and import the shared module in all other required modules.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **`MatDialogModule`** from providers

```
providers: [...],
```

Comment: No luck. Tried even removing all providers.

Comment: remove it from the entry components dialogcomponent

Comment: Still nothing. I've been struggling with this for hours so that I have tried before.

Comment: i am sure that you are missing some imports

Comment: I wil still try to look into it. I try to post more information when I get the chance

Comment: oh dear! but certainly you need to remove it from the provider. upvote if this helped

Answer (score 0):

in my case i forgot to add it to the routing module.

`const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: MyDiaglogComponent},`